# Find text differences in C# and use them to revert text to previous state

Tags: c#, .net, string, text

Do you know of any library written in C# or compiled for .NET that I can use to find the differences between two strings (what have been inserted and what have been deleted) and then use this difference to revert the text to the original state (instead of having to save a copy of the original text)?

Comment: where are you saving? are talking about version control, audit, etc.?

Comment: wouldn't you need to have a saved version of the original string in order to compare in the first place?

Comment: I'm making my own simple source control app. It will monitor a folder for file changes and save these changes somewhere. Then you can see the changes made from any date to any other date and then this files could be reverted to any previous state. I do not want to use subversion or anything like that.

Comment: @Majd: you only need to save the files being currently compared. Then you can throw it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you're looking for is something that solves the [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem**. There are commercial libraries that implement that, but you can find a free version that you may be able to use or adapt on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DiffAlgorithmCS.aspx.

If you're interested in the core implementation of such an algorithm, you can also find it on [Wiki Books Algorithms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence).

Comment: I just got that one at CodeProject but it doesn't come with a "revert" method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you basically looking for something like a diff utility, but in C#?

You can try to adapt one of these:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/differ.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/CsLCSDiff.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about source control, which gives you this feature as part of a system that does what you are asking for.

Subversion is easy to understand, and its windows client is user friendly.

Recently I started using Git because it seemed interesting, and I like the way it works for teams.

Also, WinMerge is a tool that does what you want outside the context of SCM.

Comment: Yea, Subversion messed up my PC and had to do System Restore, and the other one is $49 bucks. I already have a file monitor little library. With just the string comparison library, I can make my own source control app that would do just exactly what I need and on a super simpler way.

Comment: I'm actually trying that $49 bucks one right now. I'll give it a chance. Is called Visual SVN.

Comment: That's the server component of SVN - allows you to set up the projects. Also, I use the free version.  It works well inside an intranet because it uses windows authentication.  If you don't like typing out command lines, get the tortise client.

Comment: Where is the free version? Does it work with VS? I don't need intranet or anything other than my own PC but this stuff keeps asking me for URLs and servers.